# count flagged rows on SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite.

I have a simple table

```
id  flag     
1   y   
2   y   
1   n   
2   y   
3   n
```

I need to create a query that should give the number of flagged rows

```
id No
1  1
2  2
3  0
```

if I use

```
    SELECT  Table1.ID as ID, Count(Table1.id) AS No
    FROM Table1
    WHERE (((Table1.[flag])=True))
    GROUP BY ID;
```

the `GROUP BY` will ignore the id=3.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there: instead of `COUNT`, use `SUM`, and move your `where` clause inside it as a condition.

This should work:

```
SELECT  Table1.ID as ID, SUM(case when (Table1.[flag])=True then 1 else 0 end) AS No
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: @sixfeetsix I lifted this condition from the sample in the original post, and assumed that it works. Of course I agree that some playing around with the condition may be required - this answer is only a guideline intended to help the OP in building his own working solution.

Comment: yes I see that now sorry bout that, not sure how `'y'` becomes `True` tho.